# how to edit @INC entry to include a new directory for modules

Tags: linux, perl, apache, cgi, centos

I was wondering how I can add a new directory in my perl settings to also be searched for modules to be included?

When I run this line :

```
perl -w /var/www/cgi-bin/upload.cgi
```

I get the following error :

```
Can't locate config.pm in @INC (@INC contains: . /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8) at /var/www/cgi-bin/upload.cgi line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /var/www/cgi-bin/upload.cgi line 5.
```

And I searched Google and apparently I should include `/var/www/cgi-bin` as a folder so that Perl can locate it and include it.

**MORE INFO**

here are the top few lines of the program :

```
use strict;
use lib '.';
use XFSConfig; #this was fixed by using -I command line switch
use XUpload; # this returns as an error!!!
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use CGI;
use LWP::UserAgent;
```

Comment: What is config.pm? I don't see that in the top few lines. Where is XUpload relative to your program?

Comment: well I tried to rename XFSConfig to Config thinking it would fix it, but above is the original untouched program that runs on my other servers with no issue!!! XUpload is in a folder called "Modules"relatively to my program. so its located @"/var/www/cgi-bin/Modules/"

Comment: So like I said in my answer, `use lib dirname(realpath($0)).'/Modules';`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways, many of them covered in [`perlfaq8`: How do I add a directory to my include path at runtime?](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfaq8#How_do_I_add_a_directory_to_my_include_path_%28@INC%29_at_runtime?)

1) Use the `-I` command line switch

```
perl -w -I/var/www/cgi-bin /var/www/cgi-bin/upload.cgi
```

2) Use the `PERLLIB` or `PERL5LIB` environment variables

```
export PERLLIB="$PERLLIB:/var/www/cgi-bin"
perl -w /var/www/cgi-bin/upload.cgi

PERL5LIB="$PERL5LIB:/var/www/cgi-bin" perl -w /var/www/cgi-bin/upload.cgi
```

3) use the `lib` pragma in your code

```
# somewhere near the top of  /var/www/cgi-bin/upload.cgi
use strict;
use warnings;
use lib '/var/www/cgi-bin';
```

Comment: I used method 1, and now I am getting another error and perl cant find the second file I want to include in the program, I have included the header of my cgi file in the question now, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Use #2 if you have a CGI program and can use something like .htaccess. Otherwise, use #3

Answer (score 1):

The simplest is [mylib](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?mylib).

```
use mylib;
```

It searches in a directory named lib/ and ../lib/ relative to the script. It handles symbolic links correctly.

---

If you need more flexibility, you can use [lib](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?lib).

```
use lib $lib_dir;
```

Which is the same as

```
BEGIN { unshift @INC, $lib_dir; }
```

For example, to look into the same dir as the script, you could use

```
use Cwd            qw( realpath );
use File::Basename qw( dirname );

use lib dirname(realpath($0));
```

---

You can also provide it on the [command line](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html).

```
perl -I$lib_dir script.pl
```

---

Finally, if you want to set it globally, you can set environment variable `PERL5LIB` in your login script.

```
export PERL5LIB=$lib_dir
```

(Replace `$lib_dir` with the path in question.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is very likely that you haven't spelled `Config` properly. It starts with a capital *C*, and Perl won't find the module if you get that wrong.

By default `@INC` contains `.` - the current working directory of the Perl program - as its last entry, so Perl programs will usually look for files in the same directory as the source file as a last resort.

`Config` is a standard module that is created when your copy of Perl is built. It contains all the parameters to the build. It should never be found outside the standard library folders.

Comment: Most CGI scripts are executed with "`/`" as the current directory, so "`.`" is useless for them.

Comment: And something tells me he doesn't want *`perl`*'s configuration. He should definitely not create a module called `Config`.